# Using iteration in Model Builder for Clipping features in an ArcGIS File Geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, clip, file-geodatabase

I have to Clip the data in a file Geodatabase in which there are about 80 Feature Datasets which includes about 20 feature classes in each one of the Feature Datasets.

I have created the model once which iteration of "Feature Classes", once with "Datasets" and once with " Workspace".

I was able to do some clipping but None of them do it through the whole GDB and just get the first Feature dataset. How can I make it automatically for the whole FGDB?

Comment: Should all feature classes be clipped with the same clip features? Where do you want to store all outputs?

Comment: That is true. All the Features are supposed to Clip . It is possible to save them even in a new FGDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easier with arcpy. If you dont want an arcpy solution I can delete my answer.

Script will list all feature datasets in database, and for each list all feature classes and then clip with specified clip feature. Outputs will be placed in the same feature dataset and with '_clipped' appended to name.

Make sure you have no feature datasets or feature classes in the database but the ones you want clipped.

```py
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = False #Remove this line if you want all outputs to be added to the map
database = r'C:\Somedatabase.gdb' #Change
clip_feature = r'C:\Somedatabase.gdb\eraser' #Change

arcpy.env.workspace = database
datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type='Feature')

for dataset in datasets:
    arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(database,dataset)
    features = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    for feature in features:
        arcpy.Clip_analysis(in_features=feature, clip_features=clip_feature, 
                           out_feature_class=feature+'_clipped')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your Feedback. I am not really pro in ArcPy but I am going to try it.

Comment: I tried the Code but I receive error

Comment: @Chiki2025 what is the error message?

Comment: this is the error: Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: It works strange. I have limited the featuredatasets to just two and it works. However, when I increase the number of the featuredatasets, it stocks and I get Errors.

Comment: @Chiki2025 I just tried it on 3 datasets with success. Please make sure you have no feature datasets or feature classes in the database but the ones you want clipped.

Comment: Thank you for your Feedback. I have just found out the possible reason for that. There are some feature datasets in which the Features are already clipped. As the featuredatasets are a lot, it is not possible to check them one by one. Could it be the possible error? and if yes, is there a possibilty to edit the Code in a way to eliminate the Features which are already clipped?